# Building Apache Ambari fails: connection refused

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, ambari

I am following the installation guide for Apache Ambari. I am running the Maven build, but it gives me many time the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-storm-sink-legacy:jar:2.7.3.0.0: 
Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557:
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.storm:storm-core:jar:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.storm:storm-core:pom:0.10.0.2.3.0.0-2557 from/to apache-hadoop (http://nexus-private.hortonworks.com/nexus/content/groups/public): 
Connect to nexus-private.hortonworks.com:80 [nexus-private.hortonworks.com/54.173.242.72] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]
```

Is there some workaround?

I have ubuntu Linux 19.04, the java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~19.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
```

My Maven version is:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.0
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_222, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.0.0-25-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```